# How to set checked to false if check state is indeterminate

Tags: c#, winforms

I need a check box to report False in the Checked property if CheckState property is Indeterminate. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just verify the CheckState property:

```
        bool reallyChecked = checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by deriving from `CheckBox`.